# Django Not letting save Time in Hour:Minute formate

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework

I am trying to save  time in this formate  '13:21' .  but django not letting me to do so and giving this exception

```
["'13 : 53' value has an invalid format. It must be in HH:MM[:ss[.uuuuuu]] format."]
```

my field is

```
duration = models.TimeField(null=True , blank=True)
```

my `setting.py` is

```
TIME_INPUT_FORMATS = ('%H:%M',)
```

Comment: it seems there are spaces between `13` and `53`.

Comment: yes I am using a plugin @ArakkalAbu  .

Comment: you may override [model clean methods](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/instances/#validating-objects) and remove white spaces before insertion.

Comment: @aasmpro can you give example please ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

that's better to change your frontend and send data in correct format rather than changing backend, but if you want to handle that in backend side, you can override model save method and clear `duration` spaces:

```
    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if isinstance(self.duration, str):
            self.duration = self.duration.replace(' ', '')
        super().save(*args, **kwargs)
```

this will work as long as you pass `duration` with string value, in other cases you may use `datetime.datetime.strptime()` like:

```py
import datetime
time_string = '13 : 53'
time = datetime.datetime.strptime(time_string, '%H : %M').time()
```

also this could happen anywhere (even in your API) before passing data to the model too.

Comment: actually it's in django rest framework . In override case I have to place code in Model.py ?

Comment: yes, in `Model.py` in your model, where `duration` field is. for API calls, date-time data will be passed by string values. also this could happen anywhere, even in your API too before passing data to the model.

Comment: @gamer did it helped you?

Comment: I was having difficulty so handled that on front side.

Answer (score 1):

To make things work simply add this format to formats.

```
TIME_INPUT_FORMATS = ('%H : %M', '%H:%M')
```

As you can see the spaces are also counted in as characters for example you would like to format time only with spaces - its possible just bo doing this

```
TIME_INPUT_FORMATS = ('%H %M',)
```

Comment: how to donate space ?  by this %?  I can see  space is after hour and before minute.

Comment: I don't really know what you mean by dontaing space but the format string works more less like this - everything except special signs that are listed [here](https://ourcodeworld.com/articles/read/555/how-to-format-datetime-objects-in-the-view-and-template-in-django) is treated as a static characted so the program needs it to correctly identify the date imagine this - 200325 what date is it? well unless we specify some convention we can't say but if i tell you frist two digits are current year next digit is month and last two are day it becomes clear that its 2020.03.25 so you say as '%y%m%d'